# how can I get value and compare value in this situation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='utf-8' ?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="DN"><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/RNC-14/WBTS-1/LCG-1]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ROPTIME"><![CDATA[2013-05-15T07:00:00.000+07:00:00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MAX_AVAIL_CE"><![CDATA[432]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MIN_AVAIL_CE"><![CDATA[432]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="AVG_AVAIL_CE"><![CDATA[432]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MAX_USED_CE_DL"><![CDATA[33]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MAX_USED_CE_UL"><![CDATA[15]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2283A"><![CDATA[   7.64]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2280A"><![CDATA[399]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2277A"><![CDATA[   7.64]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2278A"><![CDATA[   3.47]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C15"><![CDATA[720]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C16"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C17"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C18"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C19"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C20"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2253A"><![CDATA[ 100.00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2254A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2255A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2256A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2257A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2258A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="DN"><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/RNC-14/WBTS-10/LCG-1]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ROPTIME"><![CDATA[2013-05-15T07:00:00.000+07:00:00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MAX_AVAIL_CE"><![CDATA[324]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MIN_AVAIL_CE"><![CDATA[324]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="AVG_AVAIL_CE"><![CDATA[324]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MAX_USED_CE_DL"><![CDATA[35]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="MAX_USED_CE_UL"><![CDATA[11]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2283A"><![CDATA[  10.80]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2280A"><![CDATA[289]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2277A"><![CDATA[  10.80]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2278A"><![CDATA[   3.40]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C15"><![CDATA[721]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C16"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C17"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C18"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C19"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="M5006C20"><![CDATA[0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2253A"><![CDATA[ 100.00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2254A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2255A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2256A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2257A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="RNC_2258A"><![CDATA[    .00]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

I just want to get data of `@NAME='DN'` and value of DN is `'PLMN-PLMN/RNC-14/WBTS-1/LCG-1'`.
After that I get data of `@NAME='MAX_AVAIL_CE'` to calculate and export a report.So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return the all `COLUMNS` with the name `MAX_AVAIL_CE` in a `ROW` which have a column named `DN` with the stated value:

```
//ROW[COLUMN[@NAME='DN'] = 'PLMN-PLMN/RNC-14/WBTS-1/LCG-1']/COLUMN[@NAME='MAX_AVAIL_CE']
```